# How can I save intermediate results from a KNIME loop?

Tags: knime

I am running a KNIME workflow:
[image: workflow screenshot]

It is running over every row of my data. The problem is, I planned to run 7000 iterations and at 6800 it gets stuck. Is there a way to save the csv file? There is a problem with one row, and I want to save the result at this point in time.

Answer (score 2):

Place a **CSV Writer** node *inside* the loop, i.e. connected to the output of your **Parallel Chunk End** (keeping this also connected to the Loop End).

Configure the `If file exists…` setting of this CSV Writer to `Append`.

That should save all the data that is successfully processed by the loop.

When you say *there is a problem with one row* though, do you know what that problem is? Presumably you'd rather get the whole loop working.

You could also consider using **Try** and **Catch** nodes from the **Workflow Control > Error Handling** section to skip a chunk that causes an error.

[image]

Comment: I dont know before when the problem occurs, so it will start from iteration 0 until 4700 (for example), and then I am able to save it?

Comment: By putting an appending CSV Writer inside the loop, you'll get the results of all the chunks that are processed successfully before the error happens. With Try and Catch you would be able to get all the successfully processed chunks, only the one containing the problem row would be missing.

Comment: the row number as iteration is not inside the csv file then

Answer (score 2):

If there is a problem with a single input row, then easiest way to debug this in KNIME is often to run the input in a chunk loop.  In your case I would set the outer chunk loop to run 1 row at a time, and remove the inner parallel chunk loop until you find the row causing the problem.

Unfortunately, this might take quite some time to run.  As an alternative, try as above, but set the chunk size to say 100, and then once you know the block of rows that cause the error, use a row filter *before* the chunk loop to filter the input table to just that block of 100 rows, and then set the chunk size to 1 to see which row is the problem.

Comment: The script runs for 7 hours in total, and I don't know when the error will occur in advanced, thx